# Ways for AJAX / remoteFunction to update two or more unrelated divs (on success)?

Tags: grails

The Grails current [remoteFunction](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html) can only update one div on success (and one on error).  There are times where I want to update multiple divs (on success) using a single Ajax call.  How can one do this, other than to chain the remoteFunctions together (i.e. where the first one calls a Javascript function on success, which invokes the second remote function).   ... Is there a way to update multiple parts of a page via ajax without this type of chaining?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by getting your onSuccess function in javascript to set the html of the resulting divs. Here is a good example of how to do this - http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/04/01/filling-multiples-divs-by-single-ajax-call-using-jquery/

Cannot be done automatically.

Comment: Cool, thanks. So one could of course use a template that looks like his example, filling in the desired data in each inner div.

Answer (score 4):

You could call two remote functions separated by semi colon.

```
<g:select id='releaseVersion' name="releaseVersion" noSelection="['0':'--Select--']" from='${new Alarm().constraints.releaseVersion.inList}' onchange="${remoteFunction(controller:'alarm', action:'updateComponentByRelease',params:'\'selectedValue=\' + this.value', update:'component')};
${remoteFunction(controller:'alarm',action:'updateDiscriminatorByComponent', params:'\'selectedValue=\' + this.value',update:'subsystem')};"></g:select>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are events you can set for when the AJAX request finishes. For example:

```
<g:remoteLink action="show"
          id="1"
          update="success"
          onLoading="showProgress()"
          onComplete="updateContent()">Show Book 1</g:remoteLink>
```

Will trigger `function updateContent` when it completes http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/single.html#ajax

It doesn't look like there's a way to automatically update two divs. The only possible way it could do it is by updating both with the same content.

Comment: Juan -- you probably submitted first.  In case you have interest in how to do this, please note Tomas's answer.  It looks like you were on the right track.

Comment: @Ray: I don't  understand what you would like me to see in tomas's answer. My answer has more details and it tells you to do the same thing: Implement an onComplete callback to update both divs. Please let me know why you thought his answer was better than mine, that way I can improve future answers.

Comment: Oh, I don't know how to write that onComplete handler, to take one template/page as a response, and then update two different divs.  If you look at the article he listed, at the bottom it shows how to do that.  It really is a jquery issue in the end, but it is key jquery info/technique to update two or more divs with a single response sent back.  I knew about the onComplete handler -- even mentioned in my question -- but how to use that response to update two different divs, I had no clue.